I want to install ubuntu 24.04 but I keep getting this message I dont know what it means
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu 24.0 LTS.
Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
Result Code:E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Component:ConsoleWrap
Interface:IConsole {6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}

0X80004005 This specific error occurs when there is a problem performing an inpage operation. This error typically occurs because of corruption of the disk. From a Google search. Are you running a WSL, your question does not say you are.

This question is similar to: I can't open any virtual machine on VirtualBox. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
